# XSLT XSL:if Test Not Catching Empty Node

Tags: xml, xslt

My XML has an expected empty node: 
This node is being created by a db query to MySQL.

In my XSLT, I have tried:

```
<xsl:if test="*/DBQuery/Record/POPUP_TEXT != '' ">
<xsl:if test="count(*/DBQuery/Record/POPUP_TEXT[text()]) &gt; 0">
<xsl:if test="string(*/DBQuery/Record/POPUP_TEXT)">
```

None of them work. Either XSLT tests the node and always returns true and renders the HTML within the  block or it always returns false.

Comment: Solved: I added  
`<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`
to the top of the XSL file, right under the stylesheet declaration.

Comment: That suggests your empty node was not actually empty, but contained a whitespace-only text node. `xsl:strip-space` will indeed remove any whitespace-only nodes from the input XML, but as an alternative you could also use the expression `<xsl:if test="*/DBQuery/Record/POPUP_TEXT[normalize-space()]">`